# UPDATE  двух таблиц

Tags: sql, javascript, html, php, mysql

Имеется две таблицы связанные между собой.

Вот выборка

```
SELECT * FROM access INNER JOIN pages ON access.id=pages.id
```

А как сделать UPDATE одновременно в двух таблицах.
Что то типа

```
UPDATE access INNER JOIN pages ON access.id=pages.id SET .....
```

Имеются вот такие UPDATE-ты

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET 
name='".$name."',
title='".$title."',
active='".$active."',
keywords='".$keywords."',
description='".$description."', 
position='".$position."' 
WHERE id='".$id."' ");

mysql_query("UPDATE access SET 
admin='".$access_admin."', 
moderator='".$access_moderator."',
user='".$access_user."',
guest='".$access_guest."' ");
```

Каким образом возможно их соеденить ?

В первом апдейте можно редактировать данные, относящиеся к определенной странице.

Во втором апдейте можно редактировать данные во всех столбцах таблицы.

Получается что при редактировании страницы второй апдейт редактирует данные всех страниц.

Помогите пожалуйста не словом а делом. Если кто знает ответ подкиньте примерчик.

Comment: А что не получается? Бери этуже выборку тол ко правильно напиши update

Comment: @kostya, **you are not welcome here**. *До свидания.*

Comment: @kostya, вы бы за языком следили, сударь! В школе так общаться будете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё возможно, друг

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages p, access a SET 
p.name='".$name."',
p.title='".$title."',
p.active='".$active."',
p.keywords='".$keywords."',
p.description='".$description."', 
p.position='".$position."',
a.admin='".$access_admin."', 
a.moderator='".$access_moderator."',
a.user='".$access_user."',
a.guest='".$access_guest."'
WHERE a.id=p.id AND id='".$id."' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак, создаёшь транзакцию, обновляешь данные. Если оба успешны то сохраняешь, если нет то откатываешь:

```
try{
$pdo -> beginTransaction();
// ... update query
$pdo -> commit();
}
catch
{
$pdo -> rollBack();
}
```

Comment: ну вот примеры функций:
function mysql_tranc_begin() {
@mysql_query("BEGIN");
}

function mysql_tranc_commit() {
@mysql_query("COMMIT");
}

function mysql_tranc_rollback() {
@mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}